# unix domain sockets being awfully slow

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I got code ([client](https://github.com/nonchip/PlutoBoy/blob/master/src/core/mmu/hook_mem.c); [server](https://github.com/nonchip/PlutoBoy/blob/master/hook_hosts/common.c)) that needs to transfer data very fast between processes (to emulate an extensible memory bus; effectively I try to split the "game cartridge emulation" part from the "game system emulation" part of a gameboy emulator, so that more virtual and real hardware can be implemented/tested/debugged/etc easily).

To do this I opted for unix domain sockets using `SOCK_SEQPACKET`.

Shortened example without error handling:

```
typedef struct {
  enum {
    CONNECT,
    CONNECT_RESP,
    //... a few more packet types
  } type;
  uint16_t addr;
  uint16_t len; //note this is not the packet length, but a length field for a specific operation omitted for simplicity in the type field above
  uint8_t value;
} packet;

int server_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char* socket_path= "\0de.nonchip.PlutoBoy.hook_mem";
  int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  *addr.sun_path = '\0';
  strncpy(addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-2);
  size_t psize=sizeof(packet);
  setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &psize, sizeof(psize));
  bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
  listen(fd, 5);
  packet p;
  while(1){
    int cl = accept(fd, NULL, NULL));
    while(recv(cl,&p,psize,MSG_WAITALL)>0){
      if(p.type==CONNECT)
        p.type=CONNECT_RESP;
      send(cl,&p,psize,MSG_EOR);
    }
  }
}

//----

void client_connect_socket(){
  const char* socket_path = "\0de.nonchip.PlutoBoy.hook_mem";
  struct sockaddr_un socket_addr;
  int socket_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)
  memset(&socket_addr, 0, sizeof(socket_addr));
  socket_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  *socket_addr.sun_path = '\0';
  strncpy(socket_addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(socket_addr.sun_path)-2);

  setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &psize, sizeof(psize));
  connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_addr, sizeof(socket_addr));

  packet p;
  p.type=CONNECT;
  send(socket_fd, &p, psize,MSG_EOR);
  recv(socket_fd, &p, psize,MSG_WAITALL);
  if(p.type != CONNECT_RESP){
    perror("connect handshake error");
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

But doing that it got awfully slow, and drove my system load up to about 3-4 times the normal values, so I decided to add primitive benchmarking to it (using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and byte counters), which gave me:

```
  211091 bytes transferred in  5 s =    42218 B/s
  213748 bytes transferred in  5 s =    42749 B/s
  213062 bytes transferred in  5 s =    42612 B/s
  215458 bytes transferred in  5 s =    43091 B/s
  219934 bytes transferred in  5 s =    43986 B/s
  210272 bytes transferred in  5 s =    42054 B/s
  216723 bytes transferred in  5 s =    43344 B/s
```

how can it be the connection between two processes on a preemptive kernel via unix domain sockets is only ~42KB/s? is this really normal or am I missing something crucial here?

EDIT: I created some callgrind logs of the [client](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25869857) and [server](https://pastebin.com/LKQ1BQF0) but can't see anything really blocking me much there.

Comment: You would be much better off not using WAIT_ALL, which could block several times. Instead just copy whatever did arrive, using the length returned by `recv()` as the `length` parameter of `send()`.

Comment: @EJP as I understand it, `WAIT_ALL`/`MSG_EOR` just makes sure I don't get "half packets"? note every call to `send` and `recv` in my code is supposed to be a full/kinda-atomic operation (`recv` filling the whole struct, then having my code use it; or my code filling it and having `send` push it away to the hopefully waiting `recv` counterpart in the other process). or can I omit it since I use `SEQPACKET` anyway?

Comment: @EJP having temporarily re`#defined` both flags as `0` to test your recommendation I still see exactly the same transfer rates

Comment: Not using MSG_WAITALL should reduce latency, and doesn't destroy packet boundaries.

Comment: @EJP i tried that, doesn't seem to do anything for me. maybe something else (sound output, opengl, etc) is slowing the kernel down just enough the packets start to "pile up"? note I added callgrind logs in the question, if that helps

Comment: Unless you've skipped some code, your packets are very small.  Try adding 1k of data to them and see what your throughput is.  Could easily be the protocol overhead dominating the throughput.

Comment: @DrC the code I skipped is about 6 more enum values, so nothing getting bigger there. sadly I can't make the packets larger, as they are the emulated equivalent of individual RAM/ROM chip accesses (16bit address + 8bit data + some control stuff), which I can't predict nor buffer (as the emulated cpu depends on getting its instructions in time; I do however buffer DMA access, which doesn't help with the code being loaded way too slowly though). so the actual problem isn't as much bare throughput as it is latency.

Comment: Was more suggesting an experiment to try to see if the protocol is what is killing you.  If it is, you have to batch if you want the performance.

Comment: @DrC essentially what I did is replace stuff like `virtual_memory[address]=value` by this socket abstraction, so the "server" can decide what to do to specific addresses/etc. so I can't really buffer that into bigger packets :/

Comment: @DrC I tried adding a `uint8_t[1024]` dummy field; this increased my bare throughput by about 2KB/s on average. so yeah, the problem seems to be the small packet size but what can I do about that? batching it isn't an option, since those accesses happen more or less randomly (=unpredictable) all the time in emulation (e.g. to load the next cpu instruction)

Comment: Actually, that isn't as much of an increase as I expected/hoped for.

Comment: You could expand each read operation from single byte to an entire page of e.g. 4K and implement a page cache in the client. This is, what linux does, when an executable is paged into memory, while the CPU is fetching the instructions. The first read, that hits a new page, gets the entire page in memory, all following reads can be satisfied immediately.